# (Python) How can I apply asyncio in while loop with accumulator?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, python-asyncio

I have a block of codes that works well in fetching data from API requests to a specific site. The issue is that the site only gives me a limit of 50 objects for each call, and I have to make multiple calls. As a result, it takes me too long to finish the fetching work (sometimes I have to wait nearly 20 minutes). Here are my codes:

```
import concurrent.futures
import requests

supply = 3000
offset = 0

token_ids = []
while offset < supply:
   url = "url_1" + str(offset)
   response = requests.request("GET", url)
   a = response.json()
   assets = a["assets"]

   def get_token_ids(an):
       if str(an['sell_orders']) == 'None' and str(an['last_sale']) == 'None' and str(an['num_sales']) == '0':
       token_ids.append(str(an['token_id']))


    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = [executor.submit(get_token_ids, asset) for asset in assets]

    offset += 50

print(token_ids)
```

The problem is that the codes run through and wait for all actions to be finished before making another request. I am thinking of an improvement that when the request is sent, the offset value gets added, and the loop processes to another request, thus I don't have to wait. I don't know how to do it, I studied 'asyncio', but it is still a challenge for me. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you measured the time required for a request?  It's a web transaction, and in your code, you do only 60 of them.  20 minutes is a long time for 60 URL fetches.  If you simply make your 60 fetches and skip the processing code, how long does that take?  Have you measured the time required to execute `get_token_ids`?  It looks like a bit of string manipulation, so I would expect it to be very fast.  I suspect the use of a ThreadPoolExecutor is not helping you at all.  I wouldn't try to optimize a program's performance unless I knew where it spent its time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Requests is not asynchronous code, so each of its network calls blocks the loop until its completion.

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking

Therefore, it is better to try asynchronous libraries, for example, aiohttp:

https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp

#### Example

Create session for all connections:

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
```

and run all desired requests:

```py
        results = await asyncio.gather(
            *[get_data(session, offset) for offset in range(0, supply, step)]
        )
```

here, requests are executed asynchronously, with `session.get(url)` gets only the response headers, and the content gets `await response.json()`:

```py
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        a = await response.json()
```

And in the main block main loop starts:

```py
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    token_ids = loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

The full code

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def get_data(session, offset):

    token_ids = []
    url = "url_1" + str(offset)

    async with session.get(url) as response:
        # For tests:
        # print("Status:", response.status)
        # print("Content-type:", response.headers['content-type'])
        a = await response.json()

    assets = a["assets"]

    for asset in assets:
        if str(asset['sell_orders']) == 'None' and str(asset['last_sale']) == 'None' and str(asset['num_sales']) == '0':
            token_ids.append(str(asset['token_id']))

    return token_ids


async def main():
    supply = 3000
    step = 50
    token_ids = []
    # Create session for all connections and pass it to "get" function
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(
            *[get_data(session, offset) for offset in range(0, supply, step)]
        )

    for ids in results:
        token_ids.extend(ids)

    return token_ids


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # asynchronous code start here
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    token_ids = loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
    # asynchronous code end here

    print(token_ids)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your explanation, but how can I apply aiohttp with an accumulator while loop? Could you please provide me with some suggestions?

Comment: I have supplemented the answer